# Syntax highlighting of a submatch

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting, match

I have the following

```
syn match specialNumber /1/         contained
syn match normalNumber /\d/         contained

syn match line /^\d$/               contains=specialNumber,normalNumber

hi def link specialNumber           Special 
hi def link normalNumber            Normal
```

I expect this to highlight a line with `1` as `Special`, and a line with any other digit with `Normal`. But this is not the case. A line with `1` is always highlighted with `Normal`.
What can I do to make the code match my expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, read help pages. In this particular case, it is documented under `:h :syn-priority`.

The order matters, and **the last match has a preference**, not the first one.

BTW. Here I would rather choose `1` and `2-9` patterns, so that the collision would never arise.

Comment: I already tried the "usual" and it does not work.

Comment: This example is a simplification of the problem to understand how to solve it. My actual `normalNumber` is more complicated and involves many `\d`'s

Comment: @xvf99680 1) Yes, I guess you did and failed. And that's really a pity. You could, for example, open `:h syntax.txt` then type `/priority` etc.etc. Saying "it does not work" is a very poor excuse. 2) As I said, you need to take the declaration order into account. Sometimes, it's inevitable, but sometimes you can fiddle with your patterns to avoid that (at least, partially).

Comment: I miss understood you comment. I thought you were talking about the order of groups in `contains`. You deserve an apology. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: @xvf99680 The priority rules for the global scope and for a group scope are the same. `contains` and `contained` keywords only define which matches are tried and which aren't.